# How to toggle theano matrix based on vector of int position

Tags: python, matrix, gpgpu, theano

Using theano tensor operations, how can I toggle one cell on each row of a matrix based on a integer position indicator on the correspond row index of a vector (i.e. |v| = rows of the matrix). For example, given a 100x5 matrix of zeros

```
M = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ...
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
] # |M| = 100x5
```

and a 100-element vector of integer in the range of [0, 4].

```
V = [2, 4, ..., 0, 2] # |V| = 100, max(V) = 4, min(V) = 0
```

update (or create another) matrix M to

```
M = [
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    ...
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
] # |M| = 100x5
```

(I know how to do this iteratively using conventional codes, but I want to run it as part of an algorithm on GPU without complicating my input which is currently vector V, so a direct theano implementation would be great.)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer myself. This operation is known as [one-hot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) and it is supported as the "to_one_hot" in [Theano's extra_ops package](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/extra_ops.html). Code:

```
M_one_hot = theano.tensor.extra_ops.to_one_hot(V, 5, dtype='int32')
```